# Make Access 2007 check 2 things at once

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have the following code:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink Right(rst.Fields("Sagsnr"), Len(rst.Fields("Sagsnr")) - 9)
```

Now I have to make it check links with Right = -9 and Right = -13

```
   Application.FollowHyperlink Right(rst.Fields("Sagsnr"), Len(rst.Fields("Sagsnr")) - 13)
```

Is there a way I can make it do both at once?

I hope you guys understand my question.

Comment: Not both at once, but you can do `On Error Resume Next` before the first one, and if it fails try the second one. -- There may be a simpler way using `Replace` instead of `Right`, if you tell us the possible values of `Sagsnr`.

Comment: At the moment, the possible values of Sagsnr are: AEMA-xxxxxxx and T-xxxxxx, where x = different numbers or letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values in Sagsnr always begin AEMA- or T- and are of a fixed length you could evaluate the value of Sagsnr prior to executing `Application.FollowHyperlink` to set what your offset for the `Right()` function should be. You'll need to adjust the offset value in the below code to make sure they are correct for each type.

```
    Dim id As String
    Dim offset As Integer

    '   Find the "-" in Sagsnr and return the characters prior to it.
    id = Mid(rst.Fields("Sagsnr"), 1, InStr(1, rst.Fields("Sagsnr"), "-") - 1)

    Select Case id

        Case "AEMA"
            offset = 13

        Case "T"
            offset = 9

        Case Else
            ' Unknown type
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    Application.FollowHyperlink Right(rst.Fields("Sagsnr"), Len(rst.Fields("Sagsnr")) - offset)
```